# How do I write the value of a variable to a textbox from a class in VB?

Tags: vb.net, forms, class, oop, textbox

So I have created a class called 'order', from which when I instantiate an object in the main form, the value of the textbox is passed through as parameter. And this is the textbox I'm trying to write to- "txttotal.text".

```
  Dim order1 As New order
    order1.AddItem(menuItem)
    order1.OrderTotal(txttotal.Text)
```

And then I use that parameter in the class method to write the value of "fullamount" to the textbox. But When I run it, and after the fullamount is calculated, nothing appears in the text box. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Should I be using a function?

```
Public Sub OrderTotal(total)

Dim fullamount As Decimal = 0

For Each item As MenuItem In Items

    fullamount += CDec(item.Cost)
    total = fullamount

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `txttotal.Text` is a `String`, not a `TextBox`. Your `Order` object doesn't know anything about the `TextBox` that that `String` came from and nor should it. You are passing in an existing `String` so that is input, not output. If that object is doing a calculation then it should pass the result of that calculation back out and the form should update the `TextBox`. Yes, you should be using a function.

Comment: + You're using the wrong data types, `Cost` should be a `Decimal` in the `Order` class. ++ You should convert the `txttotal.Text` property to `Decimal` using the `Decimal.TryParse(...)` method. Pay attention to the data types.

Comment: Turn on Option Strict in Project Properties and Tools->Options->Projects an Solutions->VB Defaults. Correct the errors that this will point out.

Comment: Do you have a custom `MenuItem` class? The Windows.Forms `MenuItem` doesn't have a `Cost` property. What is `Items`? I think we need to see your class `order`. Why are you passing `total` to a sub? Make it a Function `GetOrderTotal` and return the total.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should do it like this. First get the `total` value as the text from the `txttotal.text` then populate the `txttotal.text` with the new computed value.

```
Dim order1 As New order
order1.AddItem(menuItem)

dim total = txttotal.Text
txttotal.Text = order1.OrderTotal(total)
```

Convert your `Sub` into a `Function` which returns the value that will populate the `txttotal.Text`.

```
Public Function OrderTotal(Byval total)

   Dim fullamount As Decimal = 0

   For Each item As MenuItem In Items
      fullamount += CDec(item.Cost)
      total = fullamount
   Next

   Return total

End Sub
```